Enable metadata-hash on polkadotSDK 1.6 based parachain. But version 15 of sp-api-proc-macro is yanked
I'm trying to add the feature of metadata hashing on my chain which is updated to Polkadot SDK 1.6 but cargo fails configure:
    Updating crates.io index
error: failed to select a version for `sp-api-proc-macro`.
    ... required by package `sp-api v26.0.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `sp-api = "^26.0.0"` of package `nodle-parachain v2.5.3 (/home/simson/nodle/chain/node)`
versions that meet the requirements `^15.0.0` are: 15.0.1

the package `sp-api` depends on `sp-api-proc-macro`, with features: `frame-metadata` but `sp-api-proc-macro` does not have these features.


failed to select a version for `sp-api-proc-macro` which could resolve this conflict


looking at https://crates.io/crates/sp-api-proc-macro/versions I can see version 15 is yanked.
What workaround would solve this problem?
update
Bkchr committed this f00a911c52c047db3119dedfddc86c332ff6626b to branch release-polkadot-v1.6.0 yesterday will this be released on crates.io soon to solve this problem?
